# Is there a more efficient way to compare the items of two lists and find leftOuterItems, rightOuterItems and matchedItems?

Tags: c#, list, performance, collections, compare

We often need a way to compare the items of two lists and find which items exists only in ListA (leftOuterItems), which exist only in ListB (rightOuterItems) and their common items (matchedItems)...

I've ended up with two solutions as you can see below:

One way is to sort the lists and iterate one by one (which has a performance penalty when the collections have too many items due to sorting), and the other way is to use dictionaries and hashing (which is slower than the first way when collections have a few items - due to memory allocation etc)

*Also keep in mind that I want to compare two lists of objects eg two lists of class Person (not just primitives).. That's why I created generic extension methods

So, do you have any better idea to suggest?

Thank you in advanced!

[image: program output]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fewItemsList1 = new[] { 1, 4, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 5 };
        var fewItemsList2 = new[] { 15, 5, 14, 6, 13, 7, 12, 8, 11, 9, 10 };
        Run(100_000, fewItemsList1, fewItemsList2);

        var manyItemsList1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 100_000).ToArray();
        var manyItemsList2 = Enumerable.Range(50000, 150_000).ToArray();
        Run(1000, manyItemsList1, manyItemsList2);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Run(int count, int[] l1, int[] l2)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            l1.OrderedCompare(l2, x => x, x => x, out int[] leftOuterItems, out int[] rightOuterItems, out (int, int)[] matchedItems);
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"OrderedCompare for {count} iterations with L1 items:{l1.Count()} and L2 items:{l2.Count()} took {sw.Elapsed}");

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            l1.HashedCompare(l2, x => x, x => x, out int[] leftOuterItems2, out int[] rightOuterItems2, out (int, int)[] matchedItems2);
        Console.WriteLine($"HashedCompare for {count} with L1 items:{l1.Count()} and L2 items:{l2.Count()} iterations took {sw.Elapsed}");
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void OrderedCompare<T1, T2, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T1> source,
        IEnumerable<T2> target,
        Func<T1, TKey> sourceKeyGetter,
        Func<T2, TKey> targetKeyGetter,
        out T1[] leftOuterItems,
        out T2[] rightOuterItems,
        out (T1, T2)[] matchedItems) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        var leftOuterItemsList = new List<T1>();
        var rightOuterItemsList = new List<T2>();
        var matchedItemsList = new List<(T1, T2)>();
        source = source.OrderBy(x => sourceKeyGetter(x)).ToArray();
        target = target.OrderBy(x => targetKeyGetter(x)).ToArray();

        bool reverseCompare = false;
        int i = 0, j = 0, sourcZeroBasedCount = source.Count() - 1, targetZeroBaseCount = target.Count() - 1;
        while (true)
        {
            var end = i == sourcZeroBasedCount && j == targetZeroBaseCount;
            var sourceItem = source.ElementAt(i);
            var targetItem = target.ElementAt(j);
            var sourceKey = sourceKeyGetter(sourceItem);
            var targetKey = targetKeyGetter(targetItem);

            int diff = reverseCompare ? targetKey.CompareTo(sourceKey) : sourceKey.CompareTo(targetKey);
            reverseCompare = i == sourcZeroBasedCount || j == targetZeroBaseCount;
            switch (diff)
            {
                case -1:
                    leftOuterItemsList.Add(sourceItem);
                    i = i < sourcZeroBasedCount ? i + 1 : i;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    matchedItemsList.Add((sourceItem, targetItem));
                    i = i < sourcZeroBasedCount ? i + 1 : i;
                    j = j < targetZeroBaseCount ? j + 1 : j;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    rightOuterItemsList.Add(targetItem);
                    j = j < targetZeroBaseCount ? j + 1 : j;
                    break;
            }

            if (end)
                break;
        }

        leftOuterItems = leftOuterItemsList.ToArray();
        rightOuterItems = rightOuterItemsList.ToArray();
        matchedItems = matchedItemsList.ToArray();
    }

    public static void HashedCompare<T1, T2, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T1> source,
        IEnumerable<T2> target,
        Func<T1, TKey> sourceKeyGetter,
        Func<T2, TKey> targetKeyGetter,
        out T1[] leftOuterItems,
        out T2[] rightOuterItems,
        out (T1, T2)[] matchedItems) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        var sourceDic = source.ToDictionary(x => sourceKeyGetter(x));
        var targetDic = target.ToDictionary(x => targetKeyGetter(x));

        var leftOuterKeys = sourceDic.Keys.Except(targetDic.Keys).ToArray();
        var rightOuterKeys = targetDic.Keys.Except(sourceDic.Keys).ToArray();
        var matchedKeys = sourceDic.Keys.Concat(targetDic.Keys).Except(leftOuterKeys.Concat(rightOuterKeys)).ToArray();

        leftOuterItems = leftOuterKeys.Select(key => sourceDic[key]).ToArray();
        rightOuterItems = rightOuterKeys.Select(key => targetDic[key]).ToArray();
        matchedItems = matchedKeys.Select(key => (sourceDic[key], targetDic[key])).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the inefficiency in `HashedCompare()` is down to unnecessary enumerations and lookups in the dictionaries.  If you write the algorithm in an imperative style you can avoid all that and the code becomes, in my opinion simpler to follow:

I second @00110001 suggestion that you should use a proper benchmarking framework as the differences between the different implementations are in the same order of complexity.

```
public static void HashedCompare<T1, T2, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source,
    IEnumerable<T2> target,
    Func<T1, TKey> sourceKeyGetter,
    Func<T2, TKey> targetKeyGetter,
    out List<T1> leftOuterItems,
    out List<T2> rightOuterItems,
    out List<(T1, T2)> matchedItems) where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    var sourceItems = source.ToDictionary(x => sourceKeyGetter(x));
    var targetItems = target.ToDictionary(x => targetKeyGetter(x));

    matchedItems = new List<(T1, T2)>();
    leftOuterItems = new List<T1>();
    rightOuterItems = new List<T2>();
    foreach (var sourceItem in sourceItems)
    {
        if (targetItems.TryGetValue(sourceItem.Key, out var targetItem))
            matchedItems.Add((sourceItem.Value, targetItem));
        else
            leftOuterItems.Add(sourceItem.Value);
    }

    foreach (var targetItem in targetItems)
    {
        if (!sourceItems.ContainsKey(targetItem.Key))
            rightOuterItems.Add(targetItem.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Just a small nitpick: in the LINQ terminology the key-retrieval lambdas are called selectors, not getters ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__)). Also these selectors are commonly accompanied by an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`, so that you can, for example, match files and directories based on the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` that follows the comparison rules of the OS.

Comment: Regarding the naming of selector vs getters, I agree with you and would usually call it a selector however I chose to stay as close to the OP's code as possible.

Comment: TryGetValue() is indeed much faster than my original solution with Linq .Except()

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Except` and `Intersect` which both work on `Sets` (a light weight hashset) and will work *O(n) linear time complexity*

```
var list1 = new[] { 1, 4, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 5 };
var List2 = new[] { 15, 5, 14, 6, 13, 7, 12, 8, 11, 9, 10 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list1.Except(List2)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", List2.Except(list1)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", List2.Intersect(list1)));
```

**Output**

```
1, 4, 2, 3
15, 14, 13, 12, 8, 11, 10
5, 6, 7, 9
```

As to whether it's faster or slower, you would have to *benchmark*, however my gut feeling is they will be more efficient and faster.

---

On the topic of benchmarking

[image]

Use a reliable tested framework like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), you are likely to get the results wrong in unlimited ways if you roll this yourself

Comment: Sure, but I want to compare any object... not just primitives... for example two lists of class Person

Comment: @askoutaris just implement `IEqualityComparer` there are many duplicates for this and also an example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0

Comment: Yes, IEqualityComparer is a good solution when both lists are of the same type. However, it's not a generic solution. I have to create a IEqualityComparer for each type. Also, I tried it and is much slower than the above solution with keySelectors and TryGetValue